# Can not reshape after numpy.bincount() (ValueError)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I generate the `b` array using `np.random.uniform()` I can reshape it with no issues (so I can multiply it by the larger array `a`). But if I try the same line generating `b` using `np.bincount()`, I get a

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 7 into shape (20,)
```

even thought both the `a` and `b` arrays have the exact same shape in both blocks.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 20)

# Works
b = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 7)
b.resize(a.shape)
d = b * a

# Does not work
c = [0, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 0]
b = np.bincount(c)
b.reshape(a.shape)
d = b * a
```

Comment: Why would bincount output have the same number of elements as the input?

Comment: See edited question please. I removed the random generation of integers.

Comment: `c` has 7 unique numbers starting from 0, so the bincount has 7 elements. Hence, we can't reshape an array with 7 elems to a shape of 20 elems.

Comment: `resize` is not `reshape`.

Comment: `resize` just discards elements (if the new shape is smaller) or adds elements (if the new shape is bigger) - `reshape` keeps the number of elements.

Comment: Ugh I didn't even realize I was using `reshape` instead of `resize`! This question should be closed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPys [`resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) can change the total number of elements. It discards elements if the new shape is smaller and fills elements with zeros in case the new shape is bigger (or repeats the arrays values in case you use the [`resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html#numpy.resize) function). So it's no problem if you "resize" an array from size 7 to size 20.

> Return a new array with the specified shape.
>
> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a. Note that this behavior is different from a.resize(new_shape) which fills with zeros instead of repeated copies of a.

However [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) needs to keep the number of elements constant. That's why you can't reshape an array of length 7 to an array of size 20.

> Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.

---

Also the `reshape` method (and function) don't change the array in-place. Only the `resize` **method** does that (the `resize` **function** also doesn't!).

Thanks @user2357112 for pointing that out!

Comment: The `resize` *function* repeats elements; the `resize` *method* pads with zeros. Also, the `resize` method mutates the array, unlike the `resize` function and both variants of `reshape`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I clarified the answer. I thought the resize function was used - my mistake for not reading the question carefully enough.

Comment: Thank you guys! You managed to turn a poor question into a useful answer.